# Getting TypeError: expected string or buffer when trying to parse time string in the json?

Tags: python

I have a json which has a field timestamp which looks like this

```
"timestamp" : { "$date" : "2014-09-27T05:08:25.021+0000" }
```

When I am trying to parse it like this `json.loads(jsonMap['timestamp'])`, I am getting the following error

```
 obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Does anybody have any idea how to resolve this? How do I get the value from the json?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse an ISO 8601-formatted date in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-to-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date-in-python)

Comment: @Amadan That link is about how to parse the time string. I can not even get the value from the json?

Comment: If your question is about parsing JSON, we need to know what `s` and `_w` are. Minimal, correct example, you know? I parse your JSON excerpt just fine: [`json.loads('{' + str + '}')`](https://repl.it/Bt6f/0).

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you the answer: it's expecting a string (or a buffer) which means it's not getting one - it's getting something else.

What is it getting? A dictionary. Why is it getting a dictionary? Because that's what the value of that key is. You've already parsed it: `jsonMap['timestamp']` isn't a JSON string - it's the interpreted value already.